# How to configure Chrome to open magnet URI's with Deluge?

Tags: chromium, bittorrent, transmission, deluge

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 (natty) from 10.10, I can no longer open magnet (torrent) links in Chromium, and set deluge to automatically open and accept the URL.

(Edit: currently ".torrent" files are not a problem, but [magnet URL's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme), e.g. of the form "`magnet:?xt=urn:...`", are now the only problem. Not sure if something updated...?)

Rather, now *only* transmission will automatically open <s>torrents</s>, magnet links, etc. There doesn't seem to be a way to set deluge to be the default torrent client. (And, there also doesn't seem to be a "default application" setting for BitTorrent client to replace transmission w/ deluge.)

Notes:

- I found some old threads on this issue, and only a [one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1747876) or [two](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=36587) newer ones. The newer threads seem to suggest xdg-open is to blame. But not many people seem to be running into this problem, so... maybe it's just me?
- Not using Firefox, so manually setting apps for mime-types or extensions doesn't work (that's not an option in chrome/chromium, AFAIK -- you have to rely on the OS)
- I uninstalled transmission, and then basically nothing happened when clicking on torrent/magnet links.
- running from the shell also opens transmission (not deluge): `xdg-open "magnet:?xt=urn:bt..&tr=http://tracker.....com/announce"`.

My current URL handlers are:

```
$ gconftool -a /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet
command = deluge "%s"
needs_terminal = false
enabled = true
```

The only work-around I have (which does work) is to rename `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk{,.bak}` and create my own `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/transmission-gtk
#!/bin/bash
deluge "$@"
```

Anyone else run into this, know of a bug, workaround, or...?

Comment: This may seem a dumb question, but... what if you right-click a .torrent file in nautilus, go for properties, "Open With" tab, and select Deluge? Does it work? Does Deluge at least *shows* in that list?

Comment: Not a dumb question... The problem is _only_ with magnet url's; ".torrent" files are not a problem. With the magnet url's, there is no file to download. It's like "ftp://..." or "https://..." or file://...".  Using nautilus, I can double-click and deluge opens the torrents; using "xdg-open foo.torrent", torrent files are opened correctly with deluge.  _However_ using links like "magnet:?..." or even "xdg-open 'magnet:?...'", transmission opens regardless of any gconf settings I make. (I'll see if I can clarify this in the question...)

Comment: Actually, originally torrent files were also a problem; but now, surprisingly, torrent files do indeed work.   I don't know if something changed (it would have to be xdg-open?) ...or if I changed something to make it start working. So, now I can use torrent files as a work-around. Magnet links are (obviously?) better to use in certain situations, though... would be nice to find out if that is indeed a bug or my (broken) configuration.

Comment: Hum, nice clarification. Yes Im aware of what magnet links are.. its similar to apt links. Im just not sure WHO handles them - the OS or the Browser. I mean... do the browser tell passes the magnet request to OS, or does it handle and launches the app itself? In that question it may lie your answer. Meanwhile, Ill check the behaviour of my FF and Chromium

Comment: Firefox handle's its own application launchers (or... at least it used to?)...  I just googled again and found a recent forum posting with the answer (see below...)  Thanks for the comment, it forced me to look into this again.  I had just been living with manually opening the magnet links. Kind of a pain.

Comment: Ive actually never used magnet links myself. I usually click the .torrent files, and have the browser to silently download and open them. Its always erasier to configure xdg-open with plain files than a "non-standard" url. It can be configured in Nautilus > right-click > Open With (or Properties > Open With Tab)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is in fact a bug in deluge packaging (or, perhaps deluge is the same & everything else changed around it... depends on your perspective, I guess.)  See [the forum topic here](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=36587) for the details.

Basically, setting up xdg-open's config via gconf-editor didn't do anything to resolve the issue, since as of Natty the file-open functionality is handled by gvfs-open, which doesn't use gconf settings. Rather, gvfs-open looks at the ".desktop" files bundled with each application to determine what file types can be handled (if not installed, run `sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin`).

From the forum posting, the `/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop` file has a couple issues; it should say `Exec=deluge-gtk %U` (rather than just "`Exec=deluge-gtk"`) so that the argument is passed to the application. Second, rather than just `MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;` it should say `MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;`.

The update should be coming through soon... Here is the link to the [updated desktop file](http://git.deluge-torrent.org/deluge/tree/deluge/data/share/applications/deluge.desktop?h=1.3-stable&id=57ac902d50eb629ee8c79a6a87b05198d38ff078) should you want to make the change yourself; just run `sudo update-desktop-database` and everything just starts working (don't even have to restart chrome/chromium).

Comment: Humm, nice! +1 for that (but it sucks when you have to answer your own question, doesnt it?). Anyway... if Natty requires that .desktop files now have parameters in the Exec statement, wow, basically ALL of my software wont work (I use Mint 10)

Comment: It makes no sense for Natty to require parameters in the Exec statement. ITs a huge change that will require rewriting every .desktop for every application. Would be much better to leave the files untouched and tweak gvfs-open call to automatically append any passed parameter to the command in the Exec statement. At least untill ALL applications are fixed.

Comment: I should mention that I also installed this to make it work (if you don't have this, you may get different results):  sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin

Comment: If you don’t want to mess with files in `/usr` you can also copy the `.desktop` file to `.local/share/applications/` and run `update-desktop-database .local/share/applications` after that.

Comment: @Bombe: nice approach. And you probably don't even need to update-desktop-database. Gnome usually has daemons that auto-refresh the menus when new files are dropped in that directory.

Comment: Just hacked Azureus to work. Got the xdg/gvfs bs to kick in Azureus (using all other answers here!): Testing with xdg-open on command line showed that. However, Azureus didn't react. In the azureus.desktop file, it had Exec line with %f. Changed that to %U as mentioned in this answer, and now it works.

Answer (score 38):

### For 12.04 up to 16.04

In 12.04 and 13.04, deluge *does* include `x-scheme-handler/magnet=deluge.desktop;`
in the desktop file. In my case, transmission  was still opening magnet links. I had to tell `gvfs-open` preferring deluge with:

```
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop
```

### For 18.04

`gvfs-mime` was deprecated and 'gio mime' used instead:

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop
```

Comment: Working for 16.04LTS

Comment: Working for me in 18.04 with FF

Comment: Thanks. Currently i'm getting the error: Failed to load the information for the manager, Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

#### Ubuntu

Recently it is also needed to add the following line to ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list under [Added Associations]

```
x-scheme-handler/magnet=deluge.desktop;
```

#### Kubuntu

On Kubuntu however, you have to create the following file in ~/.kde/share/kde4/services/magnet.protocol

```
[Protocol]
exec=deluge "%u"
protocol=magnet
input=none
output=none
helper=true
listing=false
reading=false
writing=false
makedir=false
deleting=false
```

*Note: Don't forget to relog after these changes.*

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, and after installing Deluge, I just only need to run this command in order to get Chromium use Deluge to open magnets:

```
xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Also may need:

gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop

Which does the same thing, but also gets the gnome conf database (which may or may not be the same DB as the freedesktop DB)

Answer (score 3):

I did all of this and it didn't work.

After having tried everything else I saw, I finally managed to make magnet links open in `deluge` not only by changing

```
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;
```

to

```
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

in `/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop`, but also by removing

```
x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

from `/usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop` before running

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Answer (score 2):

This was supposed to be a comment, but I needed to upload a pic, so here it goes:

- In my setup, both FireFox 3.6 and Chromium 11.0 opened Deluge
- Chromium asked for a confirmation that gives us a hint of whats going on:

[image]

This shows that Chromium does NOT launch Deluge directly... it relies on `xdg-open` for that. Meaning all that must be researched (and fixed) is the OS, not Chromium. Nothing to fix or change in the browser.

This is not an answer, but it will focus your efforts in the right place... what you must fix have nothing to do with the Browser, but the OS.

Comment: you can add pics in comments ;)

Comment: you can? wow! How? Anyway, that would look awful i think :P

Comment: It's interesting that this says that xdg-open is used to open the magnet links.... I can't get that dialog, since my chromium "remembers" my preference for automatically opening magnet urls..! (And, yes, I tried "clear auto-opening settings", even after managing to get it to be un-greyed...)  But as part of my "fix" in my answer, I did also install gvfs-open (sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin). Now, if you check the shell script for /usr/bin/xdg-open, the function "open_gnome()" just calls gvfs-open (if it exists), otherwise it calls gnome-open. (What a mess...)

Comment: see Oli's comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1396/how-do-i-add-images-to-posts  ;)

Comment: @michael_n: thats why i posted the screenshot.. i figured it would help you to know for sure that Chromium relied on `xdg-open` (as it should indeed... non-standard URI's must be handled by OS, not Browser)

Comment: @michael_n: Ive checked here, in 10.10 xdg_open also chooses between gvfs-open or gnome-open. But I dont think it is a mess... `xdg-open` is meant to be distro- and destop-agnostic. It even checks for KDE. So it tries to find the best handler given your setup.

Comment: @michael_n: the puzzling part is: if you didnt have gvfs-open installed until now, wouldnt your xdg-open try gnome-open? And doesnt gnome-open rely on gconf, which you had correctly configured for magnets? So how come it didnt work before?

Comment: @MestreLion - yes, we've come full circle. That was my original question...! :-) ...gconf doesn't seem to make a difference here: changing "/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet" does nothing.  Running: gnome-open "magnet:?xt=urn..." still uses /usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop (strace gvfs-open & gnome-open verifies this). Changing deluge.desktop to "Exec transmission-gtk %U", both gvfs-open/gnome-open now open transmission. "What a mess" is perhaps an overstatement; perhaps "What a transition" is more accurate. Probably no need to postulate further here what's going on behind the curtain.

Comment: Put more succinctly, /usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop had an entry for "MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;", but deluge.desktop didn't have an entry for MimeType=magnet... Therefore, transmission handled magnet URL's. The gconf settings didn't make a difference.  (But, it is cool that pictures can be posted in questions & comments. Something positive came out of this...!)

Answer (score 2):

Download and install [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/79003). Now you should be able to quickly add torrent files to Deluge 1.2+ WebUI in Chrome!

Tested on 11.10. For other OS'es you must try out yourself, but I expect it'll work fine on them too.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 10.04 with Deluge and chrome I had to do:

```
gconftool -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command "deluge-gtk '%s'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 10.10, tried a bunch of things, this was what worked:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command "/usr/bin/deluge-gtk %s"
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/needs_terminal false -t bool
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this really solves the issue, but at least it works for me (lubuntu 12.04):

- Hover your mouse over the magnet link until the magnet address is shown at the bottom of your screen.
- Right-click and select "Copy link address".
- Open Transmission and under "File" select "Open URL".
- Paste the URL in the box and start downloading.

By the way, I fear I'm necroposting a little right now, but the above solutions didn't work for me and my answer might be useful to others, since this page was the first result when I searched this issue on Google.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Mint 16 Petra, I had to edit the Transmissions.desktop file in the applications folder, but also in /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache, rather than mimeapps.list

Also, there is another mimeinfo.cache file in /home/[user]/.local/share/applications that can be edited as well, but I assume this would only affect the current user, where as the one in the applications folder affects all users.

Hope this helps out.

EDIT:

Haa, it appears this functionality was built into the latest versions of Deluge. You can go to Edit -> Preferences -> Other -> and associate default magnet links with Deluge.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like now the latest releases ([ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deluge-team/+archive/ppa)) of Deluge did address the points of the selected answer. However that didn't solve my problem with Google Chrome not launching Torrents in my Ubuntu Precise 12.04.

Rather it looked like the `xdg-mime` used by `xdg-open` was not set properly. I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88769/how-to-choose-which-bittorrent-client-is-called-when-clicking-downloaded-torrent) a working solution. i.e.

```
$ xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
$ xdg-mime default deluge.desktop application/x-bittorrent
```

Then a quick check

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
deluge.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default application/x-bittorrent
deluge.desktop
```

And now it's at last working fine.

Answer (score 0):

for me what worked is i went to mimeapps.list file and added tixati as the default magnet handler - its very easy and works fast .

Create desktop shortcut link of the bittorrent client then .

Go to this file --** ( press Ctrl+H ) to show/hide files from view..

/home/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

Open the file -mimeapps.list - type this text 
 *  x-scheme-handler/magnet=tixati.desktop

click save to the application.

I use tixati for torrent . if u use another bittorrent client -- just replace *tixati* with other - eg vuze , deluge, . (download tixati from tixati.com )

If you wish to choose transmission then replace tixati with
 *transmission-gtk.desktop*

Answer (score 0):

Here's @michael_n 's answer in one script :

```
# rewrite deluge's .desktop file
sudo tee /usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop > /dev/null <<'EOF'
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Deluge
GenericName=BitTorrent Client
X-GNOME-FullName=Deluge BitTorrent Client
Comment=Download and share files over BitTorrent
TryExec=deluge-gtk
Exec=deluge-gtk %U
Icon=deluge
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;P2P;GTK
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
EOF

# set association and reload
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Woked for me on ubuntu 15.10 with default installs for chrome and deluge.

Answer (score -1):

My Chrome was using Transmission by default. I wanted to use qBittorrent. On Ubuntu 14.04 I removed Transmission using:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-gtk
```

Then I 'manually' started qBittorrent and closed it again. The next time I clicked a magnet link I was prompted by Chrome to allow it to call an external application. I allowed this and chrome then fired up qBitorrent.

So it seems that if you don't need to have more than one torrent client on your PC, by removing the others and leaving the one you want, you can force Chrome to use the desired client. A bit of a Chuck Norris solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
cd /usr/bin/

sudo sed 's/elif \[ x\"\$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID\" \!\= x\"\" \]\; then DE\=gnome\;/elif [ x"$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;\n    elif [ x"$MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;/g' -i xdg-*
```

Worked for me (Mint Mate 16 Petra).

Comment: Holy sh*t, mate, whoever told you to run this should be added to your "block" list. I stopped reading at `cd /usr/bin; sudo sed ... xdg-*` ... not every file `xdg-*` is actually a shell script; some are binary. You need to fix your system if you actually run something like this (you might be ok, since it may not have changed the files at all...)  In any case, `*_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` is unrelated afaik to the topic at hand, but even so, you just set/unset the env var; you don't `sed` all scripts in `/usr/bin`.