# magnet links on Lubuntu 12.04, how do I get them to work?

Tags: lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)
>   [How to configure chrome to open magnet url's with deluge?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44849/how-to-configure-chrome-to-open-magnet-urls-with-deluge)

i'm trying to open a magnet link in chromium on lubuntu precise.  exactly how would i get this to work?
i'm running chromium thats the standard on lubuntu. i'm pretty sure it used to work in 11.10.  i've found a little info here: http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2012/01/24/open-magnet-urls-with-xdg-open/
not sure if that's correct or not

Comment: Please reopen this question?  The solution(s) offered in [How to configure chrome to open magnet url's with deluge?]http://askubuntu.com/questions/44849/how-to-configure-chrome-to-open-magnet-urls-with-deluge did not work under my Lubuntu 12.04 install.

Comment: can i even do that if it was closed?

Comment: I think it must be someone with enough reputation and moderator status.  Were you ever able to get the magnet links working?

Comment: nope, but i've heard people say it actually works (on some pc's), but i don't believe them.  use firefox :)