# Changing the torrent programm for magnet URL

Tags: chromium, transmission, ktorrent

for the moment I'm downloading torrents via magnet sing `Transmission`, when the first time I was asked by chromium to open the magnet URL, I choosed Transmission and I checked the Remember my choice for all links of this type.

Now I want to change the default torrent program for Magnet URL I want to open them using `KTorrent`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 6):

A few things from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44849/how-to-configure-chrome-to-open-magnet-urls-with-deluge?rq=1):

Chromium - or any other browser - doesn't choose which application to use for launching any external application. It relies on the OS for that.

You can use `gvfs-mime` to reconfigure it again if you need to change your previous setting

`gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet KTorrent.desktop`

NB: KTorrent must be available. For me I use deluge so my command uses `deluge.desktop` which was available in `/usr/share/applications/`

Hope this helps out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gio mime` (`gvfs-mime` has been deprecated)

To change the default to K-torrent

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet ktorrent.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "Handlers" setting. From [this page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1382847?hl=en):

1. Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings > Show advanced settings.
3. In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.
4. In the dialog that appears, find the “Handlers” section. Click Manage handlers.
5. Use the drop-down menu next to a listed protocol to select the web service that should be used by default.

If that doesn't work then you can try deleting the correct line from the state file. [Instructions here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/K22hXwRy6zQ) shold help get you started, there for google-chrome, but should be close enough. You basically find the line in your state file, delete it, and that makes the popup show again.

Comment: This did not work for me. There was no 'magnet' or 'torrent' protocol listed in 'Handlers'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xdg-mime**:

`xdg-mime default KTorrent.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet`

Answer (score 0):

another option is to try to change this through the torrent client settings, e.g in **BitTorrent** press the **settings** icon on the middle right, then simply click **associate with torrent files** worked like a charm..