# (chrome) Set default handler for magnet links ?

Tags: google-chrome, bittorrent, xdg-open, torrent-client

When I click on a magnet link Chrome/Chromium open Transmission ...
I'm would like to change this to use Tixati

Comment: Just use `tixati` instead of `deluge` in instructions.

Comment: yes you are right and I did, but the answer is quite long and user with few experience may need an answer for tixati

Comment: also I found very confusing configure this kind of thing so having the info collected in one clean thread is valuable for me

Answer (score 3):

From this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44849/how-to-configure-chrome-to-open-magnet-urls-with-deluge/45984#45984)

> xdg-open's config via gconf-editor didn't do anything to resolve the issue: since as of Natty the file-open functionality is handled by gvfs-open, which doesn't use gconf settings. Rather, gvfs-open looks at the ".desktop" files

So here some general instruction, they should work for every client ( just wisely change `tixati` with what is required by you )

**1. Check the tixati.desktop file**

Actually `tixati.desktop` looks fine so you can skip this step

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/tixati.desktop
```

Here we need to check that:

- `Exec=tixati %U` contains the `%U`
- MimeType contains at least these 2 entry `MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;`

If not fix it and the run `sudo update-desktop-database`

**2. set default application for Magnet**

I suggest to uninstall `transmission` anyway this command should set `tixati` as default:

```
xdg-mime default tixati.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```